# Change form element invalid style when trying to submit with out click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to change the style of an element when it's invalid for example when marked as `required` but is empty.

So I tried this :

```
input:invalid { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

But because when page loads, all inputs are empty, all inputs become red. I only want my `required inputs` to become red when the user tries to submit.

So another solution was to add a class to inputs when trying to submit. Adding this class when clicking on the submit button by adding listener on button click event. Yet, you can also submit a form by pressing enter in a field so, class wouldn't be added to inputs.

We can see that the default invalid style gets applied only when we submit, even if we submitted by pressing enter. So I came to you to figure out a way to do the same but with my own style.

Comment: Put the JavaScript on the form's `submit` event, not the submit button's `click` event. Then it will run no matter how the form is submitted.

Comment: No because the submit function isn't called when it sees an empty input with tag 'required'